# Deleting AMP cache: "The requested URL /update-cache/c/s/whatever was not found on this server"

Tags: google, cache, amp, openssl

I want to delete the AMP contents of my 'amp-en.products.example.com' website. I create the following URL to flush the cache

`https://amp--en-products-example-com.cdn.ampproject.org/update-cache/c/s/amp-en.products.example.com/article?amp_action=flush&amp_ts=1609335649&amp_url_signature=foo`

When 'foo' was created by using

`echo -n >url.txt '/update-cache/c/s/amp-en.products.example.com/article?amp_action=flush&amp_ts=1609335649' && cat url.txt | openssl dgst -sha256 -sign private-key.pem >signature.bin`

and then obtaining a URL-safe base64 conversion.

However, when accessing the mentioned URL, I get a 404 error:

> The requested URL `/update-cache/c/s/amp-en.products.example.com/article?amp_action=flush&amp_ts=1609335649&amp_url_signature=foo` was not found on this server.

What am I doing wrong?